# SSL certificate on Tomcat 7 configuration

Tags: tomcat7, ssl-certificate, keytool

I've acquired a signed certificate for use in a secure connection in Tomcat 7(.0.42). Here is what I'm given:

An x.509 certificate, primary-intermediate and secondary-intermediate x.509 certificates, an PKCS#7 chained certificate, and a private key.

I imported the certificates as specified in [this guide](http://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO16181) using the x.509 certificates, then configured my SSL Connector to use the keystore, but got this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Alias name the_alias does not identify a key entry
```

I was advised to use the (also) provided PKCS#7 chained certificate, but when attempting to import it using keytool, it failed saying that it wasn't an x.509 certificate.

I understand from online lit that in the first step I was missing the "1" alias for the private key, but I have no idea how to import it. Also, I understand the PKCS#7 certificate is supposed to work fine on Tomcat, but I don't know how to import it to a keystore. I'm rather new to this, please advise!

Many thanks,
Victor.

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Comment: Thank you Michael! Sorry I didn't reply before.

Answer (score 0):

I can not check how you implement the guide, but I do recommend to start from the self-signed certificate according to instruction here:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Ensure that `keyAlias` points to the alias of the server certificate in `keystoreFile`.
The default alias for the self signed certificate is `tomcat`.

```
<Connector port="8443" 
…
keyAlias="tomcat"
…
keystoreFile="server.keystore" keystorePass="changeit" 
truststoreFile="trust.keystore" truststorePass="changeit"/>
```

When it will work, replace the `keyAlias` with the alias of the signed certificate.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your answer! I was able to create a certificate and test with it, however the setup with the provided SSL certificate is very different.

Comment: If the the self-signed certificate works for you, you should carefully add the key certificate to the keystore, CA certificate to the truststore, configure both `keystoreFile` and `truststoreFile` in the server.xml. Please pay attention for `keyAlias`.

Comment: Thanks Michael! I couldn't figure out how to do that, so I just installed APR on Tomcat, and used the APR SSL Connector, which has the ability to read in the chained certificate and private key separately.